# Is a function with a random variable continuous?

Tags: functions, continuity, random-functions

I often like to fool around on graphing calculators when I am bored. A function that can be very amusing is

$f(x) = rand \times \sin x$

Now, on my TI-84 Plus, this looks obviously discontinuous because of the poor resolution. And there can be spikes when the value of $rand$ is higher or lower than average, however I feel as the scale of the window $\to \infty $ that the probability of the function being discontinuous  would decrease because the effects on $sin x$ would be less dramatic. Now I understand that at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $f(x)$ may equal $1$, and then at $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+}f(x)$ could be equal to $0$ if $rand = 0$, however there is a point inbetween  $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\lim_{\frac{\pi}{2}^+}$, and this can be reiterated an infinite amount of times. Does this make $f(x)$ continuous?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a *function* because it may not give you the same value when you supply the same $x$ as the input. In other words, the concept of continuity does not extend to this extended notion of function.

Comment: @Tunococ So because it is random, it is no longer a function as it cannot be reproduced?

Comment: That is correct. However, this kind of extension leads to an interesting theory of random functions. For example, this question can be made more rigorous by defining $f$ as a function of two variables: $f(\omega, x)$ where $\omega$ comes from a probability space. (You can write $f(\omega, x) = \omega \sin x$ in your case.) Then you might want to ask about the probability that the function $x \mapsto f(\omega, x)$, with $\omega$ fixed, will converge when $x$ approaches a certain value, like $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Tunococ So this can be considered a function of two variables, similar to [this function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z+%3D+y+sin+x), where $y = ω$? Or I am misunderstanding that $rand$ can still be used as the input for $ω$, where an entire dimension of $x$s is then computed?

Comment: Yes. If you make it a function of two variables, it will really be a *function*, and you can use whatever concept of functions to discuss it. The way $rand$ is involved in the definition of $f(\omega, x)$ is as the underlying distribution of $\omega$, which I omitted in my previous comment. If $rand$ returns a continuous uniform random variable in $[0, 1]$, then $\omega$ would have a probability density function $\omega \mapsto 1$ for $\omega \in [0, 1]$. If you replace $rand$ with other functions (say $randn$ in MATLAB), then the p.d.f. of $\omega$ would be different.

Comment: Depends on the algorithm which the calculator uses to supply random variables, not every variable has equal probability, nor is there some good "random" character, always there is an algorithm to the random variable; calculators cannot supply "real-random variables"

Comment: @Tunococ Oh ok now I can begin to visualize what you mean... If you add an answer I'll accept:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ as you originally wrote is not a *function* in the mathematical sense because given a fixed $x$, $f(x)$ does not have a fixed value. Repeated evaluations would yield different results.

The way to formalize this is to properly introduce a random variable, say $Y$, then make $f$ a function of two variables: $f(x, y) = y \sin x$. The function $x \mapsto f(x, Y)$ is the proper definition of your original function. Note that you need to specify the distribution of $Y$ that corresponds to your $rand$ function. For example, if $rand$ is a continuous uniform random variable between $0$ and $1$, then the probability density function of $Y$ is $y \mapsto 1$ for $y \in [0, 1]$.

$f$ is now a function in the conventional sense. You can talk about its values, limits, partial derivatives, etc. We can also put randomness into our statements like $\Pr(f(\pi/2, Y) \le 1/2) = 1/2$, or $E\big[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, Y)\big] = \frac 12\cos x$.